# What was "inertial" about the Inertial Upper Stage?

Tags: space-shuttle, upper-stage

The [Inertial Upper Stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_Upper_Stage) was a rocket upper stage that could boost payloads launched on the Space Shuttle or Titan rockets to higher orbits or to interplanetary missions.

**What was *inertial* about this upper stage?**  (And couldn't whatever argument used also apply to other upper stages?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a nice article about the evolution of the IUS in [this issue of the Crosslink newsletter](https://web.archive.org/web/20140417071751/http://www.aerospace.org/wp-content/uploads/crosslink/V4N1.pdf).

Originally, NASA intended to develop a reusable "space tug" that could deliver satellites from the relatively low orbits reachable by STS to geosynchronous and other high orbits. This was a big concept that was going to take years to develop, so NASA and DOD agreed to develop an expendable *Interim* Upper Stage, IUS, to perform those sorts of satellite deployments.

As the article describes:

> At the end of 1977, NASA abandoned its plans for a space tug, so the IUS program name was formally changed from Interim Upper Stage to Inertial Upper Stage **(because it used inertial navigation).** The prime contractor was selected, and full-scale development began in April 1978.

Obviously a desire to retain the established [TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym) informed the choice of name; it's not unique in using [inertial navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system). It's a pretty poor choice of name all around; it's *two* stages, not one.

Comment: Certainly it's not unique: among others, the Centaur is a current upper stage with inertial guidance. That is a nice benefit to the payload. Without inertial guidance in the upper stage, the spacecraft must carry 30-50 m/s of ∆V to make up for injection residuals, the 3-D components of velocity errors at sustainer shutdown. With inertial guidance that can be brought to less than 1-2 m/s. You mention TLA — much light has been made of that. In Charley Kohlhase's *Voyager Trave Guides*, instead of 4-letter and 5-letter, he had *ETLA: Extended Three Letter Acronym* and *DETLA: Doubly Extended...*

Comment: Interesting, I never realized the name changed that early. There were still documents referring to "interim" in the 80s. I also thought it was called that because it was three-axis stabilized, not spinning like the PAMs. Live and learn.

Comment: I suspect it's a fundamental law of the universe that "interim" projects will outlive their intended successors, which doesn't bode well for the SLS's EUS.

Comment: @RussellBorogove That concept was expressed in my line of work with 'there's nothing more permanent than the temporary!'